# How can I access the ApplicationProperties of a service bus message in a Azure Function isolated process?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a service bus message that has some `ApplicationProperties` added to it:

```cs
ServiceBusMessage serviceBusMessage
serviceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add("TenantId", tenantId);
serviceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add("Serialization", "JSON");
```

I need to access these from my Azure function. In a [class library style function app I can use `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#usage) but there doesn't seem to be an [equivalent in out of proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68454335/im-getting-the-error-message-cannot-convert-input-parameter-when-trying-to-us)?

Comment: See this issue's [comments](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/384). It deals with properties as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much much digging I realised that the a) there is an overload for the function that includes a [`FunctionContext` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.functioncontext?view=azure-dotnet).

so my function has the following signature:

```cs
[Function("ExternalProviderChanged")]
        public void ExternalProviderChanged([ServiceBusTrigger("topic",
            "subscription",
            Connection = "ServiceBus")]
            string myQueueItem, FunctionContext context)
```

and b) inside the `FunctionContext` the application settings are available, though pretty hidden. The function context exposes the following a `context.BindingContext.BindingData` which is a `context.BindingContext.BindingData`. Inside this dictionary is a property `UserProperties` (yes the old name not the one MS changed it to) and that property contains the `ApplicationProperties` in JSON format. So for me to get property `x` I had to do:

```cs
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> bindingData = context.BindingContext.BindingData;

if (bindingData.ContainsKey("UserProperties") == false)
{
    throw new Exception("Service bus message is missing UserProperties binding data");
}

string userPropertiesStr = bindingData["UserProperties"].ToString();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userPropertiesStr))
{
    throw new Exception("UserProperties is null or empty");
}

JsonDocument json = JsonDocument.Parse(userPropertiesStr);
JsonElement xProp = json.RootElement.GetProperty("x");
string x = serializationProp.GetString();
```

Comment: I've raised a ticket in [Github to try and get this tidied up](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8063)

Comment: You might want to move it to the specific [repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues)

Answer (score 6):

I might arrive after the battle but there is an easy way to get access to the `ApplicationProperties`. Just replace the type `string` (which will return you only the content of the message) with the type `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage`.

```
public async Task OnServiceBusAsync(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(topicName: "TOPIC", subscriptionName: "SUBSCRIPTION", Connection = "CONNECTION")]
    Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
    ILogger log)
```

Then you would be able to get access to a specific custom property

```
    var vcountry = message.ApplicationProperties.GetValueOrDefault("BusinessCountry").ToString();
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` in the context of Azure Functions _isolated_ at this point.

Comment: @rvdginste yes you can, it worked for me :)

Comment: Whenever I try that, I get an error that it cannot convert a string into `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`, and according to docs it is not supposed to work.

Comment: This solution worked for me. However, the function app is running in 'InProcess'

Comment: this works with web jobs